# jquery datepicker, dates range count

Tags: jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker, date-arithmetic

i am trying to sum up or deduct dates in selected range using jquery datepicker, here is how i am doing it right now but without any luck.

```
function test(){
    var sundayCheck = 0;
    var saturdayCheck = 0;
    var totalDays = 0;

    sundayCheck = new Date($("#onlySunday").datepicker("getDate"));
    saturdayCheck = new Date($("#onlySaturday").datepicker("getDate"));

    totalDays = saturdayCheck.getDate() - sundayCheck.getDate();

    alert(totalDays);
}
```

thats a piece of code that should make calculation but what it does is just deducts days like,

24.01.10 - 06.02.10 = -18 which is totaly wrong as it should be more days its just does not consider the days and its just using first numbers of dates.

If anyone could help how to make such calculations i would appreciate the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to dtermine the number of days between two dates?

```
  totalDays = Math.ceil((saturdayCheck.getTime()-sundayCheck.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24);
```

First get the number of milliseconds between the two dates then divide by the number of milliseconds in a day. Using Math.ceil to round up to nearest integer.

Comment: it worked like a CHARM, but one question as for example using your code with mine and applying it to 30.01.2010 - 24.01.2010 equals = 6, but in reality i need result of 7 as 7 days passed. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: It probably depends on how you count the days. You are including the 24 in your count to get 7? If that is always going to be true then you need to +1 to the given expression.